# What is the syntax for named parameters in Laravel 4 routes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to use named parameters for all my routes in Laravel 4, rather than relying on the position in the route definition.  I cannot find anything in the manual that describes how to do this.

I saw this github issue that indicates this feature exists in Laravel 4: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/832#issuecomment-8217765

I've tried setting up routes with a colon prefix, e.g.

```
Route::get('{:foo}/{:bar}', function($bar, $foo) {})
```

I also tried using what appears to be the old syntax, with `(:foo)/(:bar)` rather than curly braces, but that doesn't work either.  The parameters always come through in the order they were defined in the route.

Example:

The application I'm working supports some routes that I need to maintain.  But they were not designed in a proper restful style.

> /autoaccount/user/2/3 refers to to the auto account with id=2 of the user with id=3

The new design for this is:

> /users/{userid}/autoaccounts/{autoaccountid}

So the parameters are in a different order for the new route.  I would like to point both of these routes to the same function.

Comment: Can you give an example of routes and what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have several legacy routes that I need to maintain which were not designed using a consistent RESTful style.  I would like to be able to create routes for the old URLs and point them to the same functions as some new routes I have.

Comment: I provided an example in my question now.

Comment: For legacy routes, I'd suggest rewriting them via `.htaccess` to the new routes (using `$1`, `$2`, etc in your rewrites). While `users` may be your controller, `{userid}` is not a valid action - you must know what `action` you're going to do.. then you can have any amount of parameters after that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 4 supports this as you said.

You need the variables in curly brackets as you have done, but without the colon`:`

Docs are routing are [here](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters).

Relevant example:

```
Route::get('user/{id}/{name}', function($id, $name)
{
    //
})
->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+', 'name' => '[a-z]+'))
```

Note that the `where()` portion is optional.

Check out the docs linked above for available options. Note that you can define a controller method and other options in an array passed to the `Route::method()` calls.

Lastly, see also the [controller docs](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers) for routing to a controller.